# Does setting TCP_NODELAY affect the behaviour of both ends of the socket?

Tags: tcp, network-programming, nagle

I've always assumed that Nagle's algorithm affected the socket in both directions, and that setting `TCP_NODELAY` somehow informed the remote end also to switch off Nagle.

Is that right, or does setting `TCP_NODELAY` only affect the behaviour of the end that calls it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`TCP_NODELAY` affect sending TCP segments only on the host that sets this option on its socket. That is, the peer's sending algorithm is not affected.