# socket tcp package no delay

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I want to send two packages one by one:

```py
conn.send('package_1')
conn.send('package_2')
```

The question is it will be assembled in one package, because the interval of these to package is small. I don't want this to happen. So I found `s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)`, but it still doesn't work.

In client, it still receive a package like this `package_1package_2`

[similar to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8226512/does-setting-tcp-nodelay-affect-the-behaviour-of-both-ends-of-the-socket)

Comment: That’s the way TCP works. It’s not message-based. It works more like writing a file. Send/recv is not 1:1. You need to build in a protocol such as sending message length or adding newlines. Buffer the bytes received and extract complete messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how TCP works. TCP is not a message protocol. If you want a message protocol, you have to implement (or choose) one.

Comment: So would you explain a little about `TCP_NODELAY` to me. I found this statement from `TCP_NODELAY
If set, disable the Nagle algorithm. This means that segments are always sent as soon as possible, even if there is only a small amount of data. When not set, data is buffered until there is a sufficient amount to send out, thereby avoiding the frequent sending of small packets,.`. So does nodelay still has an interval of sending time ?

Comment: @jan The implementation is free to do it however it wants to. As soon "as possible" does not mean immediately.